# Spark chaining operations

Tags: pyspark

I'm new to python and spark. Is there a way to do method chaining like Java 8 streams API? I have this in pyspark. Do I need another API like stream API?

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("MaxTemperatures") 
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

def parseLine(line):
    fields = line.split(",")
    stationID = fields[0]
    entryType = fields[2]
    temperature = float(fields[3]) * 0.1 * (9.0 / 5.0) + 32.0
    return(stationID, entryType, temperature)

lines = sc.textFile("file:///SparkCourse/1800.csv")
parsedLines = lines.map(parseLine)
maxTemps = parsedLines.filter(lambda x: "TMAX" in x[1])
stationTemps = maxTemps.map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))
maxTemps = stationTemps.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : max(x,y))
results = maxTemps.collect();
                      
for result in results:
    print(result[0] + "\t{:.2f}F".format(result[1]))
```

I get a synthax error when I want to chain the method

```
maxTemps = parsedLines.filter(lambda x: "TMAX" in x[1])
                      .map(lambda x: (x[0], x[2]))
                      .reduceByKey(lambda x,y : max(x,y))
                      .collect();
```

Comment: Please post exact error message. (also, don't use RDD APIs, it would be very bad from performance point of view - use PySpark DataFrame APIs)

Answer (score 0):

PySpark is organized by chaining transformers and estimators together into pipelines. You can read more about that [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/ml-guide.html) (old version of Pyspark but the ideas still apply). You can find more info on split and example code [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html). You might also get some use out of user defined functions for custom operations (UDFs) which you can read about more [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.udf.html).

As Alex Ott mentioned, you want to be using the modern ML API (DataFrames) and not the MLLib API (RDD) which is depreciated.